# Odd Reflections occurring within my scene

Tags: lighting

There's been odd reflections within my scene an example of this is shown below:
[image]

The My goal is to try remove the green tinge/reflection off of certain objects within the scene, the ground is creating the green diffuse.

I've tried turning off all ray visibility options on the lights and the objects.

[image]

Comment: look into your wall material settings. they cause this look. Show here your material settings, and maybe someone could suggest some solution. and even better if you'd share your blend.

Comment: Uploaded my blend file so the settings can be easily checked

Comment: First of all, you will probably want your object to be illuminated directly, right? Turn the diffuses checkbox in the world visibility [back on again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abhOv.png)

Comment: Thanks Leander, i didn't realize i had the worlds diffuse turned off which solved my problem, now when i turn off the grounds diffuse it doesn't turn the houses black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, i fixed this through turning the worlds diffuse back on as stated by Leander, then turning off the grounds diffuse which stopped the ground affecting the rest of the scene